# Java play framework null pointer exception in reflection giving file

Tags: java, reflection, playframework

In java play framework project I do not figure out in retrieving file sample.txt in same package of my current controller class.

I try with this command:

```
URL resource = MyController.class.getResource("text.txt");
```

This is my current project structure:

```
- app
---- test
--------- controller
------------- MyController
------------- text.txt
```

I have tried with a similar command:

```
 InputStream resource = MyController.class.getResourceAsStream("text.txt");
```

or

```
ClassLoader cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
File file = new File(cl.getResource("text.txt").getFile());
```

Same null pointer.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe the instruction : `cl.getResource("text.txt").getFile()` in play framework do not get the file in the path `getClass().getClassLoader()`. It can be a visibility problem. Play framework can not access to all project folder via getClassLoader(). Try to put the file into conf folder and get it with `Play.application().resourceAsStream("file.txt");`

Answer (score 0):

Controller directory it is not the execution directory, it is only for the source code files.

Work directly with ressources, for your case, intenal usages, see https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/sbtCookbook#Configure-externalized-resources

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).